# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument for udp connection

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming

The udp server and client on my local pc.

```
cat server.py
import socket
MAX_BYTES =65535

def server():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind(('127.0.0.1',10000))
    print('Listening at {}'.format(sock.getsockname()))
    while True:
        data,address = sock.recvfrom(MAX_BYTES)
        text = data.decode('ascii')
        print('The client at {} says {!r} '.format(address,text))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server()
```

Bind port `10000` with localhost-`127.0.0.1`,and listening to the message send from client.

```
cat client.py
import socket
import time
from datetime import datetime
MAX_BYTES =65535

def client():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind(('127.0.0.1',10001))
    text = 'The time is {}'.format(datetime.now())
    data = text.encode('ascii')
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        sock.sendto(data,('127.0.0.1',10000))
        print('The OS assinged me the address {}'.format(sock.getsockname()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client()
```

Run the server.py and client.py on my local pc,server can receive message send from client.

Now i change `127.0.0.1` in the line in client.py  with my remote vps_ip.

```
sock.sendto(data,('127.0.0.1',10000))
```

into

```
sock.sendto(data,('remote_ip',10000))
```

Push server.py into my vps.Start client.py on my local pc,server.py on remote vps,start them all.
In my client,an error info occurs:

```
  File "client.py", line 13, in client
    sock.sendto(data,('remote_ip',10000))
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

How to make remote ip receive message send from my local client pc?

Comment: Is your `'remote_ip'` literally `'remote_ip'`, or actually an IP-address, or a hostname?

Comment: It is an real IP address, not a hostname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things that could be happening:

1. You're not passing the remote IP correctly. Make sure that your not passing literally `'remote_ip'` and replace it with a valid IPv4 IP address string (IE: `'192.168.0.100'`) for the server. (FYI technically on the server you can just put `'0.0.0.0'` to listen on all IP addresses)
2. You could still be binding the client to the local address to (127.0.0.1), but setting the destination to a valid external address (192.168.0.100). Remove the `socket.bind` line of code in the client to test this, you shouldn't need it.

If these both don't work, then add the results of a `ping` command running on the client and targeting the server.